# Горизонтальная и вертикальная прокрутка в окне с менеджером компоновки QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qlayout, qscrollarea

Есть окно с табличным размещением виджетов в `QGridLayout`.
В качестве компонентов используются `QLabel`. Их может быть размещено как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали в любом количестве. 
Например, **`20`**x**`20`**, в итоге ***`400`***, вообщем заранее сколько будет компонентов не известно, поэтому и нужна прокрутка в окне по двум осям.

Как добавить прокрутку окна по горизонтали и по вертикали?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel

 
class MainWindow(QWidget):
 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):
    self.grid = QGridLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.grid)

    self.addComponents()
    self.show()

 def addComponents(self):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    countLab = 0
    while i < 25:

        while j < 25:
            lab = QLabel('lab_'+ str(countLab))

            self.layout().addWidget(lab, i, j)
            countLab += 1
            j += 1

        j = 0
        i += 1
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('Example')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel,
                             QScrollArea)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.addComponents()

        scroll      = QScrollArea(self)
        self.widget = QWidget() 
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)         

    def addComponents(self):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        countLab = 0
        while i < 25:
            while j < 25:
                lab = QLabel('lab_'+str(countLab))
                self.grid.addWidget(lab, i, j)
                #self.layout().addWidget(lab, i, j)
                countLab += 1
                j += 1
            j = 0
            i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('Example')
    mainWindow.setGeometry(300, 100, 480, 320)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант 2

сделать интерфейс растягиваемым:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel,
                             QScrollArea, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.addComponents()

        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()  
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()        

        scroll      = QScrollArea()  
        self.widget = QWidget() 
        layoutH.addWidget(scroll)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True) 

        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH)
        self.setLayout(layoutV)        

    def addComponents(self):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        countLab = 0
        while i < 25:
            while j < 25:
                lab = QLabel('lab_'+str(countLab))
                self.grid.addWidget(lab, i, j)
                #self.layout().addWidget(lab, i, j)
                countLab += 1
                j += 1
            j = 0
            i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('Example')
    mainWindow.setGeometry(300, 100, 480, 320)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размещение виджетов через `self` верный способ сделать интерфейс не растягиваемым (`scroll = QScrollArea(self)`) :) Создайте layout (Q*BoxLayout) добавьте на него `scroll`, а layout'у скажите `self.setLayout(layout)` Либо, изначально MainWindow от `QScrollArea` создавать и тогда вместо `scroll.` было бы `self.` Пример: https://pastebin.com/REG0jMhM

Comment: @gil9red  сделать интерфейс растягиваемым, пожалуйста :)